# How to get last updated product in Django restframe work?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here i have mentioned my model,serializer and view. Actually im new to this concepts. I don't  how to get the last added product.

**Models.py**

```
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    categories =  models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container=Category,
        model_form_class=CategoryForm
    )
    specifications =  models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container=Specifications,
        model_form_class=SpecificationsForm
    )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    reviews =  models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container=Reviews,
        model_form_class=ReviewsForm
    )
    drizzly = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    click_count = models.IntegerField()
```

**serializer.py**

```
class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Products
    fields = ('id',
              'name',
              'image',
              'categories',
              'specifications',
              'description',
              'reviews',
              'drizzly',
              'complete',
              'comment',
              'click_count')
```

**views.py**

```
class ProductsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   """
   API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
   """
   queryset = Products.objects.all()
   serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
```

Please tell me how to do that?.

Answer (score 3):

Since the last product have the highest `id` then you can try like this

```
last_product = Products.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
```

What I'm doing here is ordered all the project in reverse order ***by id*** then get first element from that.

Comment: he has no `id` field in his model

Comment: @Chiefir  You don't have to mention it in model to add id inside model Django generate it automatically

Comment: @ShubhoShaha Please tell me where i want to add this.

Comment: @Dhany P Sukumaran u have in your `view` to replace this `queryset = Products.objects.all()` line with this `queryset = 
 Products.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0]`

Comment: It throws error that AttributeError: 'Products' object has no attribute 'model'

Comment: @Dhany P Sukumaran try this: `queryset = Products.objects.order_by('-id')[0]`

Comment: Thanks but i have tried that also it throws same error.

Comment: @DhanyPSukumaran you can insert this line where you need latest product.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get last product would be:

```
 Products.objects.last()
```

With reverse(), you can do : `Products.objects.all().reverse()[0]`

For first one: `Products.objects.first()`

Is that what you want?

Comment: Where i want to add this

Comment: What do you mean by adding this? By the way, why do you need last product in product listing API?

If that the case, you can do :

`queryset = Products.objects.last()`

Answer (score 1):

You need some "last_modified" timestamp field on your model obviously - else you have no way to know when a record has been updated:

```
import time

class Products(models.Model):
   # your existing fields here
   last_updated = models.FloatField(
      "last_updated", 
       editable=False, 
       default=time.time
       )

   def save(self, *args, **kw):
       self.last_updated = time.time()           
       if "update_fields" in kw:
           kw["update_fields"].append("last_updated")
       super(Product, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

and of course generate and pass the migration.

Then you can get the last updated record using `QuerySet.latest(*fields)`:

```
last_updated_product = Product.objects.latest("last_modified")
```

I'm not using DRF so I can't tell how to plug this into your ProductsViewSet but there's certainly some documentation available...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from {app_name} import Products
Products.objects.reverse()[0]
```

Since there is a primary key **pk** as default in each model created, you can filter specifically using

```
Products.objects.filter(order_by='pk')
```

Comment: A pk can be set on the object that can't  be used to show the last added item i.e `a.id = 4` `b.id = 2`

Comment: @jackotonye what do you mean? interesting question for me. Can't we order by `pk`?

Comment: @RyanAR where i want to add this

Comment: @Chiefir you can order by a pk you need to add a field that tracks object that are updated i.e `updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)` Then you can use `Model.objects.latest('updated_at')`

Answer (score 0):

Working with filtering objects by when they are added to the database using a data time field to track the updated time will provide a less error prune way to get the latest objects.

See Also:
  [Retrieving the latest object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#latest), [Ordering model objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#ordering)

models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    categories =  models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container=Category,
        model_form_class=CategoryForm
    )
    specifications =  models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container=Specifications,
        model_form_class=SpecificationsForm
    )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    reviews =  models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container=Reviews,
        model_form_class=ReviewsForm
    )
    drizzly = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    click_count = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        # Latest by ascending updated_at.
        get_latest_by = "updated_at"
        # This will ensure the objects returned are ordered latest to earliest. 
        ordering = ['-updated_at']
```

serializer.py

```
class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Products
    exclude = ['created_at', 'updated_at']
```

views.py

```
class ProductsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   """
   API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
   """
   # Using Products.objects.latest() should return the latest using 
   # the updated_at DateTimeField. 
   # Note this will raise `Models.DoesNotExist` if there is no object.
   # Using the Model._meta.ordering the queryset should be ordered by
   # the `latest` first or you can also use 
   # `Model.objects.order_by('-updated_at')`
   queryset = Products.objects.all()
   serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
```